# Change height of UITableViewCell without heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

I had some UITableViewCells I was adding to a UITableView, but the structure of the page has changed, so now I need to add them to a UIView instead. (I'm sure this is a big red flag right here, they're going into one of several UIView's which appear when "tabs" are pressed).

Is it possible to modify their heights? I've been able to add them to my UIView by adding them as subviews in static positions (which is fine), but they're being cut off as they're no longer using heightForRowAtIndexPath to determine their height.

Here's my example, I've outlined the UIViews with red borders, so the UIView each cell is in is the correct size:

[image]

Is this possible or should I just add another UITableView inside the UIView I've moved them to?

Comment: UITableViewCells are only intended to be used within a UITableView. If you want to add these to a view you should convert the object to a UIView and just add it as a sub view of your container view.

Comment: Is there a way to convert a cell to a uiview? Or I should just construct the content differently?

Comment: You'd need to manually recreate the content as a view and programmatically add the views in a stacked order to the container view. It seems like a lot of extra work. Is there a good reason not to use a table?

Comment: Share your code, so that i can clarify. and yes it can be done by simply adding a tag to check and increase the view height accordingly

Comment: @BrianShamblen it's massive template application which I just took over maintenance on, difficult to explain but I'll try use a table instead of the uiview. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If moving the cells into another view is the path you want to go down, this is certainly possible. (Cells are after all a UIView as good as any). I would try you simply resizing the tableViewCell's `contentView`, or even turn the cell's `clipsToBounds = NO;` to avoid the clipping you're experiencing when resizing the cells.

...

That being said though, are you sure you really want to abandon tableViews? What exactly is forcing you to change the design, and why would the tableView pattern no longer be appropriate? Perhaps sharing some more details about the project and what you are trying to achieve would lead to a better solution...

Comment: its a huge project which pulls all data and design from a CMS (really odd, never experienced anything like it) to create the app and this results in weirdness in how stuff works, dynamic content is creating the cells which are put into a tableview, the cells use to be in that tableview as cells, but the design calls for that existing part to be moved into a tabbed view (as shown in my screenshot).. so that tab view is now a uiview inside a tableview. now i need to put the cells inside that uiview inside a tableview. I was trying to avoid uitableview in a uiview in a uitableview if i could :)

Comment: Sounds really painful! Couldn't you redesign the tab view to be in the same superview as the tableview rather than inserting it in the tableview itself? Are the two other tabs also supposed to display tableview-like data?

Comment: I don't think I can, as they want the tab view to move the same way a tableview moves when you pull down and release (ie bounce). I'm trying to think of how else I could do it with combinations of hiding/showing uitableviews.. but i don't think I can do it without putting that tableview inside the uiview in the tab view now that I think about it. Here's a bit of the explanation: http://note.io/16QSrzS

Comment: I ended up going with the UITableView inside the UIView inside the UITableview: http://note.io/1hXbE7D - pretty much working now, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hey Nick, just thought of your problem. If the tab-view needs to move with your tableView why not simply make a custom tableViewCell with the tab controls, then you won't have to go through that insane hierarchy (thank you autocorrect).

Comment: the tab view is already a "cell" within its parent UITableView.. if that's what you mean :) I've sorted it out and it hurts my brain trying to explain it! haha :)